# Can not use Swap file on ZFS: Files with holes

Tags: xubuntu, swap, 19.10, zfs

I'm trying to add a new `swapfile` to increase Swap Space by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04).

The `swapfile` creates successfully but, the `swapon` command won't accept it: says **"skipping - it appears to have holes."**.

I'm running Xubuntu 19.10 with ZFS on root.

Here is what I've tried so far:

### Create Swapfile

#### Using `fallocate` - failed

```bsh
sudo fallocate -l 8G /swapfile
fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported
```

It seems fallocate currently [does not support ZFS](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/326).

#### Alternative way - Using `dd` - success

```bsh
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1MiB count=$((8*1024))
8192+0 records in
8192+0 records out
8589934592 bytes (8.6 GB, 8.0 GiB) copied, 2.68284 s, 3.2 GB/s
```

### Prepare the Swap File - success

```bsh
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
ls -lah /swapfile 
-rw------- 1 root root 8.0G Dec 27 14:15 /swapfile

sudo mkswap /swapfile
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 8 GiB (8589930496 bytes)
no label, UUID=db8aa64c-734c-4eba-a803-72db681ec1a1
```

### Enable the Swap File - failed

```bsh
sudo swapon /swapfile
swapon: /swapfile: skipping - it appears to have holes.
```

From [swapon manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/swapon.8.html#notes):

> **Files with holes**
>
> The  swap  file  implementation  in  the  kernel 
>   expects  to be able to write to the file directly, without the
>   assistance of the filesystem.  This is a problem on files with holes
>   or on copy-on-write files on filesystems like Btrfs.
>
> Commands  like cp(1) or truncate(1) create files with holes.  These
>   files will be rejected by swapon.
>
> Preallocated files created by fallocate(1) may be interpreted  as 
>   files  with  holes too depending  of  the  filesystem.   Preallocated
>   swap files are supported on XFS since Linux 4.18.
>
> The most portable solution to create a swap file is to use dd(1) and
>   /dev/zero.

How can I create a swapfile on ZFS which the `swapon` command would accept?

#### System Info:

```bsh
sudo parted -l

Model: WDC PC SN520 SDAPNUW-512G-1002 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   590MB   52.4MB  ext4
 3      590MB   2738MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      2738MB  4885MB  2147MB  zfs
 5      4885MB  512GB   507GB   zfs
```

```bsh
sudo zpool list -v

NAME          SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
bpool        1.88G   131M  1.75G        -         -     0%     6%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  nvme0n1p4  1.88G   131M  1.75G        -         -     0%  6.82%      -  ONLINE  
rpool         472G   112G   360G        -         -     9%    23%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  nvme0n1p5   472G   112G   360G        -         -     9%  23.8%      -  ONLINE
```

```bsh
sudo zfs list

# https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6jDVwbhfCT/
```

```bsh
sudo lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

```bsh
sudo uname -a

Linux iCyberRoze 5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial you linked is not under the assumption that your root filesystem is ZFS.  The [ZFS manpage](https://zfsonlinux.org/manpages/0.8.0/man8/zfs.8.html#lbAN) indicates:

> **ZFS Volumes as Swap**
>
> ZFS volumes may be used as swap devices. After creating the volume with the `zfs create -V` command set up and enable the swap area using the mkswap(8) and swapon(8) commands. **Do not swap to a file on a ZFS file system. A ZFS swap file configuration is not supported.**

You may follow the instructions in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198916/926620) from stratus to get swap space working from a zvol which can be used as swap space that is part of your ZFS pool.

However, if you really want to proceed against recommendations to use a swap **file** stored in a ZFS filesystem:

`fallocate` does not work within ZFS filesystems, as you already know from the zfsonlinux github bug you already posted.  Instead of using `dd` which will be slower since it has to write every piece of the output file, you may want to quickly create a large sparse file that you can create on a ZFS filesystem, try the `truncate` command which does the same thing but works on ZFS.

```
sudo truncate -s 8G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

It still shows: `swapon: /swapfile: skipping - it appears to have holes.`

```
ls -lsh /swapfile
```

Reports `512 -rw------- 1 root root 8.0G Jan 17 18:27 /swapfile` showing that the created file takes up only 512 bytes instead of 8 GB.

Your compression settings for the ZFS filesystem that will contain this file will most likely cause the output of `dd` to be sparse anyway (taking up much less space on the disk than the reported filesize).

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8k status=progress
ls -lsh /swapfile
```

Reports `512 -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 8.0G Jan 17 18:39 /swapfile` showing that the ZFS filesystem compression settings made the complete 8 GB file fit into 512 bytes.

Instead of using a highly compressible input to `dd` of `/dev/zero` you can use the incompressible `/dev/urandom` so that it will actually take up 8 GB of hard drive space.  However from my testing, swapon still rejects it:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8k status=progress
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

It still shows: `swapon: /swapfile: skipping - it appears to have holes.`

One more experiment could be to try it in a ZFS filesystem that has compression turned off.

```
sudo zfs create rpool/swap -o compression=off -o mountpoint=/swap/
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap/swapfile bs=1M count=8k status=progress
```

And it really does write all 0's to the disk this time.

```
ls -lsh /swap/swapfile
```

This reports back `8.0G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.0G Jan 17 18:52 /swap/swapfile`

```
sudo chmod 600 /swap/swapfile
sudo swapon /swap/swapfile
```

It still shows: `swapon: /swapfile: skipping - it appears to have holes.`

My conclusion is that I can't tell that there's a way to circumvent its refusal of using a file located in a ZFS filesystem as a swap file.

Outside of the scope of this question, alternatives to using swap space on this system would be a swap partition (which I see you have a `590MB` swap partition already, or to put a swap file on a non-ZFS filesystem such as on an ext4 partition, or if disk space is unavailable, use [Zswap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zswap) (Compressed blocks of RAM used as swap space) or [vramfs](https://github.com/Overv/vramfs) (Swap space that lives on your graphics card's RAM).

Answer (score 17):

I think what you want is actually well documented on the [ZFSOnlinux](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-use-a-zvol-as-a-swap-device) page

TLDR;

```
# To set swap on a zfs drive:
zfs create -V 8G -b $(getconf PAGESIZE) -o logbias=throughput -o sync=always -o primarycache=metadata -o com.sun:auto-snapshot=false VMs/swap

mkswap -f /dev/zvol/VMs/swap
swapon /dev/zvol/VMs/swap

# IN FSTAB
/dev/zvol/VMs/swap none swap discard 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this is not what the question is about. This solution is for creating a zvol and using it as swap but, the question is about creating a swapfile on a zfs partition.

Comment: I understand the question, however, when the ZFS on Linux Project has a documented way to use swap with ZFS, that is the road you should go down.  Creating a file on a ZFS volume is going against the way ZFS is intended to be used. Therefore you may run into strange problems doing so. Ultimately, I am not sure why you would not follow the documented approach. I do not see a benefit having a file on a ZVOL that has other attributes that are not needed or may conflict or make swap useless. (Copy on Write for swap alone would be terrible)

Comment: Thank you for your concerns but, I guess then you should comment that doing so is not a good solution in your opinion instead of forcing a solution that is not an answer for this question.

Comment: So how to use encryption on that? One of the reasons that people want to use swapfile as a filesystem file is that it's easy, works, and also is covered by the filesystem encryption. Is it possible to encrypt ZVOL as well? Otherwise what's even the point in having encrypted OS, if all the contents will just be dumped to disk unencrypted through a swap file that attacker can then just read off offline disk?

Comment: @Cray of course you can encrypt it. If you've set up encrypted ZFS on root (available in Ubuntu 22 via the installer) you will see two pools when running `zfs list`: `bpool` and `rpool`. The first one is not encrypted, but `rpool` itself and anything under it is, so all you have to do is replace `VMs/swap` in the answer above with `rpool/swap` and that would mean that the encryption is inherited. This can be easily verified via `zfs get encryption`. Note that it will also inherit the `compression` setting which is `lz4` by default.

Comment: `cannot open 'VMs': no such pool`

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (and for over 5 years at least) this is absolutely NOT recommended, see this bug: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/7734
Any kind of swap: swapfile, or ZVOL as swap is risking OS crashes.

Your command does not work, as you are creating a swapfile on a ZFS.